# How do I get .wav files made on the iPad into dropbox?

Tags: ipad, audio, dropbox

I have an iPad Mini, and I have iElectribe which allows me to make music loops and render them as .wav files.  I want to use them in other apps and also store them in Dropbox or Google drive, but neither app lets me see anything but photos, videos, spreadsheets and .doc files.

How on earth do you get things you make into one of those services?  P.S. I don't own a Mac.

Comment: The on-line docs for iElectribe say you can use [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com) to upload and share files. I don't know if this will work for you, tho'. This looks like a cool app. I'm downloading it now!

Answer (score 2):

You can access the exported .wav files using the iTunes app on your Mac or PC when the iPad is plugged in through USB:

[image]

Select the Apps collection in the Sidebar, then scroll that window down to File Sharing. In the File Sharing list, you'll find iELECTRIBE, with all the exported .wav files. Drag the files from this list to your Desktop or folder. There seems to be no other way but to drag.

Until the developer creates the hooks that allow it to access Dropbox or Drive, this is the only way, other than SoundCloud.

Comment: In general I'm trying to avoid going to the computer at all for this.  I like this answer, and I will probably mark this as the solution, but I am still curious if there is some way to do this on the iPad itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this app but IOS apps kinda work "backwards" compared to how Macs and PCs works. In other words you can't open a file that then opens in the app of your choice.

In IOS you can only operate on a file if the app allows it. You can only open (or save) a file on IOS if the app is designed to do so. So your app needs the option to save the .wav files in Dropbox or Google Drive. If it can't you are out of luck.

Often that will show up under the sharing button (box with an arrow pointed up) tap on that button and select what app to open it with. If it allows saving to Dropbox (or whatever...) you would have the option of sharing it with Dropbox.

It's an odd way of working with files if you come from a Mac or PC background but has it's own logic and makes sense once you understand the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two apps that will handle this- [AudioCopy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audiocopy/id719137307) (free), and [AudioShare](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audioshare-audio-document/id543859300) (Paid) which copy audio from one app to another.  AudioShare allows upload and download to Dropbox, converting, trimming, normalizing and converting audio.  Not ideal to have to use an app do this, but it seems pretty solid so far.

Comment: For those of you using iTunes, I would suggest using IconDaemons answer.